# How to sum max from date range in one cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a column with dates which looks like this:

```
24-7-2002
25-4-2004 
13-4-2012
6-9-2018
25-4-2004
8-11-2022
etc...
```

I would like to find out how many times the highest date appear and sum them together in one cell preferably without helping columns. Is that achievable in one-line formulae?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on what do you mean by **`"and sum them together"`** ...could be:

- **`=COUNTIFS(A1:A; "="&MAX(A1:A))`**
- **`=COUNTIFS(A1:A; "="&MAX(A1:A))*MAX(A1:A)`**